# HTTP response API REST returning null c#

Tags: c#, api, rest, http, response

I'm trying to get the response from an http api rest link, but i don't know why, the response is empty, even testing the endpoint on postman and in my browser, that returns the correct. The code i'm using for getting the response is:

```
private static string connect(string url, string method, string data)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        if (data.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(data);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
        }
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream strReader = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (strReader == null) return "";
                using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(strReader))
                {
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(objReader.ReadToEnd()).data; //objReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And calling it like this:

```
String response = connect("http://31.214.245.211:8080/ProjectM-WS/webservice/rest/ping", "GET", "");
```

Any idea of where I can be wrong?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: The last line shoudn't be just `return objReader.ReadToEnd();`?

Comment: It was, i thought was not working that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thought that didn't work, that's becouse i commented it, but now it does.

```
private static string connect(string url, string method, string data)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = method;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            if (data.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(data);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
            }
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream strReader = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (strReader == null) return "";
                    using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(strReader))
                    {
                        return objReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```